# SSIS export to Excel template - keep row height

Tags: excel, ssis

I have a following excel 2007 template (.xlsx):

[image: excel template]

I have set up an SSIS process to copy that template and populate the first two columns with data as the file will be printed and then signed by order recipients. Everything is going well except for one thing - after the process populates the template with data, the cells don't retain their size - making signature cells too small.

[image: crap format]

Any ideas on how to force excel to keep the cell heights ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever has a similar issue, I managed to find a workaround. Instead of using SSIS I'm using SSRS where I keep the cell height by adding an "invisible (white text on white background) column at the end. I set up an SSRS subscription to automatically export the data and send as an Excel.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to create a macro that runs when the workbook is opened and it sets the row height using the Range.RowHeight property, here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193926.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately the mgmgt doesn't want me to send files with Macros. I managed to solve the problem in another way.